# Simple PHP code not working on mobile

Tags: php

THis may be super basic, but I have not been able to resolve this after spending hours!

I am running PHP 7 on Ubuntu 16.1.

The PHP file is EXACTLY as follows

```
  <?php

header("Content-type: application/javascript");
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

ExpandShortLink();


function ExpandShortLink()
{

    // get URL
    $URL_To_Expand = $_REQUEST['url'];
    // for short links, get the full links

    // get full URL
    $arr_URL_Header = get_headers($URL_To_Expand, 1);
    $strLink        = $arr_URL_Header['Location'];

//echo $URL_To_Expand;
    //print_r($arr_URL_Header);

    if ($strLink) {
        if (is_array($strLink)) {
            $Full_URL = array_pop($strLink);
        } else {
            $Full_URL = $strLink;
        }
    } else {
        $Full_URL = $URL_To_Expand;
    }

    echo $Full_URL;
}
```

--> produces the url I enter as a "url" parameter on desktop. But nothing on mobile!

On some reading, I found that in sometimes PHP interprets everything after "//" as a comment and that may be happening here. But then why does it happen on mobile only? Also, andy suggestions on resolving this will be great!

Thanks much for your help,

You can see this live [here](http://buya2z.net/test/test_Ajax.php?url=http://example.com)

If you click this on desktop, you will see http:// example. com. However, on mobile it will return http:

Comment: php is run server side - so mobile? irrelevant

Comment: The second code snippet has a PHP error; it's missing a semicolon after defining `$url`. That aside, PHP is run on the server, not the client, so it doesn't matter if the client is mobile, tablet, computer, etc.

Comment: Are you sure the second piece of code is the exact code of your php file?

Comment: @Dragon - yes, I know that. And thats why I never bothered checking it. Now I just figured that an ajax call from mobile does not work.. so I dug deeper and called the PHP directly.. It should not be device dependent, but somehow it is. I am confused!

Comment: to little info to go on, good luck

Comment: @ChrisForrence - indeed, that was a typo on this site. My original code is fine with a semicolon.

Comment: Thanks fo ryour responses.. let me paste the actual live link for you to check

Comment: I have provided the exact code, as well as a love demo link where this is happening. ANy help will be awesome!

Comment: Without running the code I'm 100% sure that there's no problem with your php code. Also calling it from mobile doesn't matter, as others have pointed out, since PHP executes on the server side. Are you loading your php file via some kind of AJAX call? AJAX happens on the client side and may therefore be influenced by the client (i.e. browser). Your html and/or css may be relevant too. In short: you've not provided the code where the actual problem is.

Comment: I tried your link on my droid, it looks fine to me.

Comment: You can just click that link I provided in the question on desktop and on mobile and you will see that the result are different. Yes, I was originally calling it through Ajax.. but the problem is still there even if I call the php directly.

Comment: works fine on mobile fire fox android

Comment: Thanks for trying @Dagon - I am testing on Chrome/Android. Can you please try Chrome (Android)?

Comment: ditto for chrome. works fine

Comment: @Dagon - thanks for checking this for me. I am not sure whats going wrong here.. does not work for me! I will try borrowing other phones and trying it there..

Comment: Update on this: I tried accessing the link using other browsers (native Android browser and Dolphin browser) and the link works fine. The only way I can reproduce the problem is by using CHrome browser. So I guess something is broken in my specific chrome. I will uninstall chrome and reinstall and post result here. However, thanks much everyone.. this site is more helpful than I thought it would be!

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how Chrome for Android handles the `application/javascript` Content-type. Maybe someone could shine a light on that? It's a long shot though.

Comment: @user2693053 - bingo! I removed the line containing application/javascript and it works fine now. So.. that line is definitely causing me problems! Not sure why.. but maybe I can just take off that line and it seems it should work well?

Comment: I think the recommended content-type for json responses is `application/json`. So if you're going back to calling this with ajax you'll want to use that -- if you're looking to return json.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this qualifies as answer, but I wanted to put a note here for anyone else who may be facing a similar problem.

I was using the PHP pasted above for an ajax call. I tried using text/plain instead of application/json and now it works across all browsers and all devices (as far as I could test).

Not sure why application/javascript was causing problems on mobile chrome, but I think text/plain makes sense as I was just passing back a text string instead of a javascript.

As I said it probably is not the fully qualified answer, but hopefully it helps someone in future!

Comment: Your script produces the string `http://example.com` and pretends it is Javascript. The browser ignores `//` and everything after it until the end of line because `//` introduces an [end-of-line comment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics#Comments) in Javascript. You probably don't want the text to be used as Javascript by the browser (it is not valid Javascript); however, you provided it bad directions, don't blame it for misunderstanding them. `Content-Type: text/plain` is the best option here. PHP is not guilty.

Comment: @axiac - makes sense. Though what is unsual is that the problem only was on Chrome browser, and that too only on mobile. If the direction was incorrect, I would have expected all browser and all devices to behave similarly.. apparently Chrome browser on mobile (and that too, only some versions) ignore anything after //...